# cell data format problem while getting php excell output

Tags: php, excel

i created an application that takes the excell output of a table.There are long numbers in table cell.When i took the output the cells that have long numbers are seen like that 1234+E34.how can i fix that?Thanks for advance...

Comment: the long number must be seen as it is.For example;
23456789021345 must be seen as 23456789021345 not like 23456+E32

Comment: @cubuzoa: Must it be a number, or can it be a string?

Comment: it doesn't matter because this number is in html table row and column.I convert this number to excell.Excell doesn't show this number as i wrote earlier

Comment: How are you writing this data to Excel? Are you simply writing a CSV file, or using a PHP library to write an Excel BIFF file? If the former, then the data is still the full number and you can subsequently apply a format mask within Excel. If the latter, what library are you using?

Comment: For understanding easy here is some part of my code

header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel; name='excel'");

    header("Content-Disposition: filename=".$file_name);

    header("Pragma: no-cache");

    header("Expires: 0");
echo $html_codes;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you're not actually writing an Excel file: It looks as though you're writing an HTML file but sending headers to the browser telling it that it's an xls file...
Excel can then identify that HTML, and parse it into a structure that it can display.

You have a couple of alternatives.

The first is to create a genuine xls file rather than trying to con the browser and Excel. The Second option: instead of writing the value as

```
12345678901234567890
```

write it as

```
="12345678901234567890"
```

Answer (score 0):

This will display in excel as "12345678901234567890" (with Quotes)

To avoid this, Use intval(12345678901234567890) in php, This forces Excel to treat this number as an integer